# ¿Cómo abrir una ventana desde otra ventana con un botón?

Tags: java, javafx, interfaz-gráfica, intellij-idea, fxml

Tengo la ventana principal, pero cuando el usuario entra a su ventana todo funciona normal, pero cuando el usuario abre otra ventana a partir del boton que aparece me da un error que es el siguiente:

**No controller is specified for the top-level element**

Lo estoy haciendo en FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>
    <top>
        <TextFlow styleClass="alert, alert-success">
            <Text text="BIENVENIDO ¿EN QUE LE PUEDO AYUDAR?" styleClass="strong"/>
        </TextFlow>
    </top>

    <left>
        <VBox>
            <GridPane hgap="5" vgap="7">
                <padding>
                    <Insets topRightBottomLeft="10"/>
                </padding>
                <Label alignment="CENTER_LEFT" text="¿Qué servicio desea pagar?"  GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
                <ComboBox fx:id="cmbServicio" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="0">
                    <items>
                        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                            <String fx:value="Agua"/>
                            <String fx:value="Luz"/>
                            <String fx:value="Telefono"/>
                            <String fx:value="Cable"/>
                            <String fx:value="Gas"/>
                        </FXCollections>
                    </items>
                </ComboBox>
                <Label text="Monto: " GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
                <TextField fx:id="monto" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
                <Label text="No. Referencia: " GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
                <TextField fx:id="referencia" GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
                <Label text="Telefono: " GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
                <TextField fx:id="telefono" GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
                <Label text="Todo pago de servicio genera una comision de: $ 10.00" GridPane.rowIndex="10" GridPane.columnIndex="0" styleClass="alert, alert-danger"/>
                <Button fx:id="btnRe" onAction="#btnRecargas" styleClass="btn-lg, btn-info" text="Recargas" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="6"/>
            </GridPane>
        </VBox>
    </left>

</BorderPane>
```

Y ademas en el botón y su onAction=**"#btnRecargas"** me lo marca en rojo y me da error de arriba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la raíz  del fxml  el nodo debe tener un atributo `fx:controller`  cuyo valor es la ruta de la clase que se debe asignar como controlador

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="ruta de la clase "
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
```